# how redirect every subfolder content to another location

Tags: .htaccess

please I have this:

```
index.com/abidjan/apartment-for-rent
index.com/abidjan/house-for-rent
index.com/abidjan/office-for-rent
index.com/blog
index.com/login
```

I want to redirect every page which contains abidjan to : `http://www.index.com/rent`

I tried:

1- `RewriteRule ^(abidjan)/ http://www.index.com/rent [NE,L,R=301]`

2- `RewriteRule ^(abidjan/*) http://www.index.com/rent [NE,L,R=301]`

3- `Redirect 301 /abidjan/ http://www.index.com/rent`

but don't working

Comment: Even though the capturing is superfluous, both of those RewriteRules should work. Do you maybe need `RewriteEngine on` first?

Comment: To me it is unclear from the question what "index.com" and "index.login" should be. Please be precise in your question. Are those folders?

Comment: Also please state that _if_ you are using a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") instead of the central configuration: where is that file located?

Comment: yes i have write  RewriteEngine on:

Comment: #arkascha,
i use configuration file (".htaccess")